# Nextjs server component is caching not refetching

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have the following setup for my main page:

```
async function getUserTaskCheckpoints(userId: string, taskId: string) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/user/${userId}/${taskId}`,
      {
        cache: "no-store",
        next: { revalidate: 5 },
      }
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
}

export default async function Dashboard({ params }: UserIdProps) {
  const { userId, taskId } = params;
  const userTasks: TCheckpoint[] = await getUserTaskCheckpoints(userId, taskId);

  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background overflow-hidden">
      
      <div className=" bg-yellow-300 flex flex-1">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className=" bg-black min-h-screen w-full">
          <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col py-20">
            {userTasks !== null && userTasks.length > 0 ? (
              userTasks.map((checkpoint: TCheckpoint, index: number) => {
                const direction =
                  index % 2 === 0 || index === 0
                    ? "xl:justify-start"
                    : "xl:justify-end";

                return (
                  <div
                    key={index}
                    className={`flex justify-end ${direction} w-2/3 mx-auto bg-black relative`}
                  >
                    <Checkpoint
                      direction={direction}
                      checkpoint={checkpoint}
                      userId={userId}
                    />
                );
              })
            ) : (
              <p>Loading....</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I'm simply fetching then passing to the Checkpoint component, which is here:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";


import React, { ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { useState, useTransition } from "react";

type CardProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Card>;

interface CheckPointProps extends CardProps {
  direction: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  checkpoint: TCheckpoint;
  userId: string;
}

const Checkpoint: React.FC<CheckPointProps> = ({
  className,
  checkpoint,
  userId,
  ...props
}: CheckPointProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [editCheckpoint, setEditCheckpoint] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [selectedCheckpoint, setSelectedCheckpoint] = React.useState<Note[]>(
    checkpoint.notes
  );

  async function updateTaskCheckpoint() {
    try {
      const newCheckpoint = { ...checkpoint, notes: selectedCheckpoint };
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newCheckpoint),
      });
      startTransition(() => {
        // Refresh the current route and fetch new data from the server without
        // losing client-side browser or React state.
        router.refresh();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  
  return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={updateTaskCheckpoint}>Click me</Button>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(checkpoint, null, 2)}<div/>
    </>
  );
};

export { Checkpoint };
```

The functionality of both fetches work but even when I reload the browser, the cached data is being displayed and the response is the same. My PUT request in the Checkpoint component is not correctly updating items either (I'm getting an ambiguous error with a greater pointer pointing to my fetch and saying: "TypeError: Failed to fetch").

I know NextJs caches requests by default, which is why I included the useTransition hook from another post I found but that doesn't work either.

Anyone know what's going on? I'm quite new to Nextjs